# How to create more states in react? Is the number of properties of react state fixed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I understand I could simply add properties together in one go. `this.state={a:'1','b':2}` . But what if we want to add extra properties to the `state` object, not just in the `constructor`, or if the properties need to be added on a condition.

Is it only supposed to work on a fixed number or properties? (I am aware of `dictionary` and `arrays` as elements of a `state`. )

```
constructor(){
   super();
   this.state = { item: 'first item' }
   this.state = { item2: 'second item' } // Or += append are not accepted. 
}
```

*Apparently, a React `state` is a `JS Object`* So, `this.state.item2= 'new item';` works.

*Answered by `Andy Ray` and `Mark E` in comments below. The other portion of the question: how to dynamatically create state is added by 
`The Reason` and marked it as answered*

*Thanks, everyone*

Comment: State is just a javascript object, there's nothing magic about it. You can do `this.state = { items: [ 'first item', 'second item' ] }`

Comment: Correction: the second assignment should be `item2` I meant to add another properties to the state object. not adding an extra to existing state's property.

Comment: You can also do this: `this.state = { item: 'first item' }
   this.state.item2 = 'second item' ` Since the state is like any other JS object you may read a little bit more about objects, this is not related to react.

Comment: I was pretty sure I tried that already. wasn't working. I thought state was a different thing. Fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* have dynamic states like so:

```
class DynamicStateBasedOnProps extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super();
    this.state = { static: 'I am static' };
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    const stateBasedOnProps = Object.keys(this.props)
      .map(key => ({[key]: this.props[key]}));

    this.setState(dynamicState)
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
      {JSON.stringify(this.state)}
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `static` do as an object do? Is it considered a normal key?

Comment: @theMobDog yeap

Comment: Thanks. Even tho my question was (1) misleading. (2) there was an obvious mistake, your answer added to the other part of the question: how to dynamically create states.

Answer (score 1):

You are able to modify `this.state` object outside of a constructor function through `this.setState({...})` and it is totally fine to add there new properties because it's just an JS object. Though, be aware, that every modification of the `this.state` leads to `render` method call.

More on this - https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Thank you for the link and pointing out modification -> `render`.